# Unable to install Solana tool suite (Windows)

Tags: windows, powershell, visual-studio-code, cmd, solana

I followed this guide:

[https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools#:\~:text=Windows-,Download%20the%20binaries%20by%20navigating%20to%20https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com,archive%20using%20WinZip%20or%20similar](https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools#:%5C%7E:text=Windows-,Download%20the%20binaries%20by%20navigating%20to%20https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com,archive%20using%20WinZip%20or%20similar).

However, when i proceed with the steps it doesn't seem to work right. I have tried so many options. Ubuntu works however i do not want to use the platform because there is some confusion for me.
Basically when I run this command:

curl https://release.solana.com/v1.10.4/solana-install-init-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.exe --output C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe --create-dirs

The output is the file that I have attached.

But then, when I run this command,

C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe v1.10.4

This is the output: The system cannot execute the specified program.

When i run the same command in PowerShell, it says "The file or directory is corrupted and unreadableAt line:1 char:1 +C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe v1.10.4.

I am not quite sure what to do so I can install this Solana tool suite.

Thanks in advance!

I have tried many things, I am not going to be using ubuntu ever again, i want everything to be with cmd and in the windows 10 system while coding in VSC.

Comment: Hey Yusuf, welcome to StackOverflow. I wish I had some help for you but I've actually ran into the same issue. If I get it figured out I'll come back and let you know.

Comment: Hey there! The answer i have marked as the solution worked for me! Try it out, see if it works for you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured out the issue.

There aren't Windows compatible files (.exe) for all of the Solana releases. The guide tells you to use v1.10.4, but after manually going through the releases on GitHub, I found that v1.9 is the latest version with an EXE listed. So run the commands as the guides describe but instead of v1.10.4, pass v1.9.7 like this:

```
https://release.solana.com/v1.9.7/solana-install-init-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.exe
```

After download completes, when it's time to run the next command, do the same thing, substitute 1.10.4 with 1.9.7 like this:

```
C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe v1.9.7
```

This will install Solana, and from there, you can follow the guide accordingly. When you run solana-install update, it should update from v1.9.7 to v1.9.14.

Answer (score 0):

ok mate, here is the complete solution:
step 1:
open your VScode as a Administartor(right click on the vscode icon, open as adimistartor).

step 2:
Open a new teminal in vscode and paste this link and press enter:
curl https://release.solana.com/v1.9.7/solana-install-init-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.exe --output C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe --create-dirs

step 3:
Your solana folder should be in this directory as default:
C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe
so find this directory end be sure to be in there with your terminal.

step 4:
type this in the terminal:
solana-install-init.exe v1.9.7
and press enter.

step 5:
once is done, kill the open terminal and open a new one and go again to the same directory C:\solana-install-tmp\ and type just the word:
solana
press enter and you will see all the data successfully installed.

step 6 (last):
in the same terminal type:
solana --version
press enter and you'll see the version which means you got full solana with no issue.