# Solana Installation

Tags: solana, solana-cli

I am using latest Windows OS and I want to download Solana.

website :  https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools

So, I followed as the Solana guide described I run my CMD as Administrator and execute this following command

cmd /c "curl https://release.solana.com/v1.16.14/solana-install-init-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.exe --output C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe --create-dirs"

this program gets execute very quickly within 10s and download corrupted exe so when I run the following command

C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe v1.16.14
"The system cannot execute the specified program".
I get that message

I turn off the firewall and defender and try to download but the corrupted exe downloaded. I try running in PowerShell I get this error message saying,

Program 'solana-install-init.exe' failed to run: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadableAt line:1 char:1

- C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe v1.16.14
- 

At line:1 char:1

- C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe v1.16.14

I try several times but same result corrupted exe.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71654323/unable-to-install-solana-tool-suite-windows

Comment: You should use WSL for solana installation it is the recommanded way.